# Why is the moon jumping to another position when I am trying to drag the sun?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Every time I click to drag the sun, the moon which was initially on the left side of the sun moves to the right side of the sun instead. I didn't put it anywhere in my CSS to put it in that position. I am not sure why it is doing that. http://whatisupson.tumblr.com/

```
    <style>
        /* Colors */
        body {
             background: url(http://i.imgur.com/aZty7Mq.png);
             animation: mymove 4s linear infinite;
             -webkit-animation: mymove 4s linear infinite;
             -moz-animation: mymove 4s linear infinite;
        }
        @keyframes mymove {
            0% { background-position: 0 0; }
            50% { background-position: 40% 0; }
        }
        #moon {
            position: absolute;
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
            top: 3%;
            left: -10%;
        }
        #dark_sun {
            position: absolute;
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            top: 20%;
            left: 10%;
        }
        #sun {
            position: absolute;
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            top: 20%;
            left: 10%;
        }
    </style>

    <html>
    <body>
            <img id="moon" src="http://i.imgur.com/o7cwLDa.png">
            <img id="dark_sun" src="http://i.imgur.com/f3UFHb7.png">
            <img id="sun" src="http://i.imgur.com/DGkZYZQ.png">
    </body>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
    var width = 300;
    var sun = $("#sun");
    var dark = $("#dark_sun")
    var moon = $("#moon")

    sun.draggable({
      axis: "x",
      containment: 'body',
      drag: function() {
        var x = sun.offset().left + (sun.width() / 2);
        var total = $(window).width();
        var heightPct = Math.pow((total / 2) - x, 2) / Math.pow($(window).width() / 2, 2);
        console.log(x, $(window).width(), heightPct * 100);
        this.style["margin-top"] = "" + Math.round(heightPct * 30) + "%";

        dark.css({
            left:x -(sun.width()/2),
            marginTop: heightPct * 30 + "%"
        });
        $(this).css({
            opacity: 1-(x/total),
            marginTop: heightPct * 30 + "%"
        });

        moon.css({
        left:x -(sun.width()/2),
        marginTop: heightPct * 30 + "%"
        });
        $(this).css({
            opacity: 1-(x/total),
            marginTop: heightPct * 30 + "%"
        });
      }
    });

    </script>
    </html>
```

Comment: A better question is: 'Why is the moon out at the same time as the sun?'

Comment: I'll fix that later. At the moment I am just worried about this.

Comment: In `moon.css`, is it's `left` supposed to be based of the suns position?

Comment: Yes, it is supposed to be based on the sun's position.

Comment: Well that's wrong, because each time on drag, `left` is being updated with the suns position. That means, each time the moon will be beside the sun.

Comment: @MunizaSiddiqui i would say try looking into your javascript from where you are changing the position of sun and moon. Because right now as you are moving sun same query is also affecting moon.

Comment: That's the point. My plan is to have the moon behind the sun, so it can gradually turn into the moon like I did with the sun, but that's obviously not working since it keeps on jumping to a different position.

Answer (score 0):

You have this:

```
var x = sun.offset().left + (sun.width() / 2);
...
moon.css({
    left:x -(sun.width()/2)
});
```

When you add `sun.width() / 2` to `left` and then subtract it later, you are left with `left`.  You may as well have put:

```
moon.css({
    left: sun.offset().left
});
```

Your moon image is 500px wide, but your sun image is only 300px wide.  The actual moon part of the image is roughly the same size as the sun image, but has extra padding, pushing the moon further to the right.

Since their top left corners are positioned in the same location, the moon appears to the right of the sun because it is wider.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that. But if I keep the size constant in all three elements (sun, dark_sun, moon) then the moon would appear too small compared to the other two.

Comment: While debugging, give your images a border.  That will help you better visualize what is happening.  http://i.stack.imgur.com/ezRwm.png

Comment: @MunizaSiddiqui - Use images that are all the same size, and use a draggable container.  It works way better:  http://jsfiddle.net/cxo7bru9/